# Is it possible to make a map item frame invisible in Minecraft 1.16.5?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I know you can make item frames invisible with texture packs, but those don´t work with map item frames. Does anyone know if there is a way to make the item frame invisible / or make it so the texture blend in with a block so it looks invisible?

Comment: Just clarifying, is this on a server, or a singleplayer world?

Comment: single player at the moment but the map is made for multiplayer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you an item frame that is invisible, not matter what you put in it.

```
/give @s item_frame{EntityTag:{Invisible:1}}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
data merge entity @e[type=item_frame,sort=nearest,limit=1] {Invisible:1b}
```

This makes the closest item frame invisible.